# Sort a JTable with date in a column

Tags: java, sorting, date, jtable, rowsorter

I have a JTable that has a column with a date in this format: "Mon Nov 19 18:03:23 WET 2018". I want to  sort my rows by the date.
I've tried using TableRowSorter but I can't sort it by the date.
Is that any way?

```
TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> (tableModel);
    timeline.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

I add the content to the rows like this:

```
tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{"Twitter", t.getCreatedAt().toString(), t.getText()});
```

Thanks :)

Comment: *"Is that any way?"* - Convert the "text' to an actual comparable value, like `LocalDateTime`, then it will work automagically

Comment: `getCreatedAt` suggests that the values are already some kind of date/time value. Stop converting them to strings and use `TableCellRenderer`s to "display" the data. This is a common task, which is demonstrated in [How to use tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) along with sorting

Comment: I've removed the ".toString()" in getCreatedAt(), now how can I sort the column by date?

Comment: As per the [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) section, you implement the `TableRowSorter`. Appreciate that SO is not a replacement for good documentation, tutorials and effort.  If you have tried implementing the functionality as described, you should also provide that in your post, then we will be in a better position to guide you

Comment: DefaultTableModel does not provide the type of each column, since it does not override [getColumnClass](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#getColumnClass(int)).  This means that, in addition to removing the toString from your data, you will need to tell the sorter to use a non-string comparator for that column.  For instance, `sorter.setComparator(1, Comparator.naturalOrder());`